# Check Out Files in Mercurial / Hg

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

I learned version control with Subversion, and now I am trying to use Mercurial. In Subversion, I had one project in a repository by itself, and I could check it out into my Visual Studio Projects folder and work on it there. Now I am using a Mercurial repo with more than just my project. I have a separate local copy and central copy. The standard way of modifying the local copy is to modify the files directly in the repo, but I don't like that, because I can't relocate anything if need be. Is there a way to check out my project to wherever I want? I don't like the edit-copy-paste-commit approach.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't like about the standard way (modifying the files directly in the repo). What do you mean with "because I can't relocate anything if need be"?

Comment: The code for all the company's projects is in the local repo, so it doesn't make sense to copy it all to the Visual Studio Projects folder if I'm just going to be working on a certain set of files. Visual Studio by default creates a new project in the Projects folder, where I have all my VS projects. But now I have to keep all my version-controlled projects in the repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this:

> The code for all the company's projects is in the local repo

Quote from ["What Mercurial can't do"](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UnderstandingMercurial#What_Mercurial_can.27t_do) in the Mercurial documentation:

> Many SVN/CVS users expect to host related projects together in one
>   repository. This is really not what Mercurial was made for, so you
>   should try a different way of working. In particular, this means that
>   you cannot check out only one directory of a repository.
>
> If you absolutely need to host multiple projects in a kind of
>   meta-repository though, you could try the Subrepositories feature that
>   was introduced with Mercurial 1.3 or the older ForestExtension.
>
> For a hands-on introduction to using Mercurial, see the Tutorial.

--> When you use a distributed version control system like Mercurial, you should try to create one repository per project.
If you do it like this, your problem just goes away because if you need to modify Project X, you just clone Project X's complete repository to your machine, and that's it!

Coming from Subversion, maybe you should read a tutorial that explains the difference between SVN and HG, for example one of these:

- [the official one](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tutorial)
- [Hg Init](http://hginit.com/) (by Stack Overflow's co-founder Joel Spolsky)

Comment: Unfortunately, the decision to put everything in one repo was made long before I came along, and I don't have much say about it. I take it I have to either copy/paste or tell Visual Studio to go to the repo?

Comment: @kendfrey: Sorry to hear that, but the decision to use HG instead of SVN **and** sticking with the old decision to keep everything in one repo was not a good one and shows that the person(s) who decided this didn't really know about the differences between SVN and HG. If there is no way to change any of this (show them this answer here!!), I'm afraid you have to use one of the dirty hacks/workarounds you mentioned.

Comment: Well, project-per-branch and `hg clone -b` can (partially) help in current state. But splitting projects is more correct way, definitely

Comment: @kendfrey - you have to move your files (one time, by hand) from path-based project to at least branch-based. If you can't create branches on "central" repo, I'm afraid, better will be not use Mercurial at all or start Mercurial-course from scratch

Comment: It souns like a good idea. The problem is that the rest of the company will probably not listen to the new guy that just learned to use Mercurial yesterday.

Comment: @kendfrey: Okay, then go to one of the senior Mercurial "experts" and ask him this exact question you asked us (how to check out only one project, because cloning the repository with all projects takes too much time). Maybe they found a better workaround/dirty hack, maybe your question makes them think whether they are using Mercurial the correct way.

Comment: The easiest way to split up this giant repository is using the `convert` extension with some filemaps. It isn’t that much work usually, just needs to be done, and the developers need to update their checkouts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `hg pull -u /path/to/central/repo` ?

Comment: I want to get only certain files, not all, from my local repo to my filesystem and back. I already have the local repo.